# Automapper before/after map callbacks during mapping

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

I'm using *ASP.NET Core* and *Automapper 6.1.0* ,

I have two types that look like this

```
public class ExampleDTO
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public ProviderDTO Provider { get; set; }
}


public class Example
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid Provider { get; set; }
}
```

*ProviderDTO class (which is irelevant in this case)*

```
public class ProviderDTO
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**AutoMapper configuration looks like this:**

```
CreateMap<Example, ExampleDTO>().ForMember(x => x.Provider, opt => opt.Ignore());

CreateMap<ExampleDTO, Example>().ForMember(dest => dest.Provider,
                                           opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Provider.Id));
```

When I map from Example to ExampleDTO, I want to pass the value for ProviderDTO type.

I tried something like this.

`_mapper.Map<ExampleDTO>(example, opt => opt.AfterMap((src, dest) => dest.Provider = myProvider));`

I get this

`'object' does not contain a defenition for 'Provider' and no extension  method`

Is this achievable? If yes, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: The Provider is an object (ProviderDTO) or GUID? show provider class...

Comment: @Ardit that's what I'm trying to map, when Destination is DTO map an object, else map a GUID

Comment: @Ardit i've added the `ProviderDTO` class, it's irelevant

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Before-and-after-map-actions), you may need to provide both the source and destination type, such as:

```
_mapper.Map<Example, ExampleDTO>(example, opt => {
    opt.AfterMap((src, dest) => dest.Provider = myProvider))
});
```